# Is it possible to restrict modifications of AD group membership to a specific computer / IP?

Tags: active-directory, security

I am trying to set up a Powershell script to automatically add some users to an AD group on a scheduled basis. When I try to add the users, I get the following error:

```
Add-ADGroupMember : Insufficient access rights to perform the operation
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "Workfront_Users" -Member $FoundUser.SamA ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Workfront_Users:ADGroup) [Add-ADGroupMember], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Insufficient access rights to perform the operation,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.AddADGroupMember
```

I do have the ability to add users to the group and I have confirmed that I have   ActiveDirectoryRights : WriteProperty on the group.

When I brought up the concern to a colleague, they showed me the "right" way to add users to a group by connecting through RDP to one of the DCs and using the users and groups tool to add people through the GUI. If I do it this way, I'm able to add users, but I want to be able to automate the process.

The way I'm interpreting this is that the ability to modify AD groups is somehow restricted to certain machines (or perhaps even locally to the DC itself) even if a user has the correct rights. My question is: Is this a restriction that can actually exist? I don't know much about security configuration of AD so I may be  making up security policies that don't actually exist.

Comment: Did you run powershell as administrator? This doesn't actually answer your final question, but it should fix the problem for you

Comment: @Drifter104 That did resolve the problem I was having. I didn't expect to need to do that, since I'm performing a domain action and local admin rights shouldn't come into play, but I'm sure MS had a good reason for that. Thank you for solving the root cause of my question, to which I assume the answer is "no, that's silly".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

AD doesn't have such restriction. A few things you can try: Double check the the syntax of the script, try it on DC directly, upgrade to latest powershell version, etc.